# Firebase storage download images

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

How would I retrieve images from firebase storage and append it to an HTML create table? I have tried to retrieve images stored in my firebase storage and place them into an image frame in an HTML table correlating to data labels retrieved from firestore. Here it the code I am using.

```
var imageRef = storage.ref(itemCategoryArray[i] + '/' + itemNumberArray[i] + '.jpg');

imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
     document.getElementById("itemImage").src = url;
});
```

When I run the code, separate images it do not append to the table matching the data I retrieved from firestore rather only one image is added to the first row and it does not even correlate to the item-number in the table row.

Comment: You're constantly setting the URL to the same element in the HTML: `document.getElementById("itemImage").src = url;`. If you want to show multiple images, you'll have to set each URL to a different element. How to do that depends on your HTML structure.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?! Can you share your code if you did.

Comment: I keep getting storage not defined?